# Recursion with matrices - Rotten Oranges

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Given a matrix of dimensions `n*n` where each cell in the matrix can have values `0`, `1`, or `2` with the following meanings:

```
0:empty cell
1:cells have fresh oranges
2:cells have rotten oranges
```

Determine the minimum time required for all the oranges to be rotten. A rotten orange at index `[i,j]` can rot other fresh oranges at indexes `[i+1,j]`, `[i,j+1]`, `[i-1,j]`, and `[i,j-1]`.  If it is impossible to rot every orange then simply return -1;

Below is my attempted solution

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void recur(int a[100][100],int t[100][100],int count,int i,int j,int n)
{
    cout<<i<<" "<<j<<endl;
    if(i<0||i>=n||j<0||j>=n)//if out of boundary stop
    {
    //  cout<<"1\n";
        //return;
    }
    if(a[i][j]==1)  //if fresh orange then recur from here too
    {
    //  cout<<"2\n";
        t[i][j]=min(count,t[i][j]);//take this case 2 1 1 2...Third 1 can be rot in 2seconds as well as 1 second so I sotre minimum of both

        recur(a,t,count+1,i+1,j,n);//again recur in 4 directions
        recur(a,t,count+1,i,j+1,n);
        recur(a,t,count+1,i,j-1,n);
        recur(a,t,count+1,i-1,j,n);

    }
    else if(a[i][j]==2)//if already a rot orange no need to check in 4 directions as I am checking for every rot in loop in main()
    {
    /// cout<<"3\n";
        t[i][j]=0;//already rot so time required =0 seconds
    //  return;
    }
    else if(a[i][j]==0)//if empty space stop
    {
    //  cout<<"4\n";
    //  return;
        //cout<<"hi\n";
    }

}
main()
{
    int a[100][100],t[100][100],n;//a is input array and t is array whihc stores time required to rot each fresh orange
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;++j)
        {
            cin>>a[i][j];
            t[i][j]=INT_MAX;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;++j)
        {
            if(a[i][j]==2)
            {
                recur(a,t,1,i+1,j,n);// recursion starts for top bottom left and right
                recur(a,t,1,i,j+1,n);
                recur(a,t,1,i,j-1,n);
                recur(a,t,1,i-1,j,n);

            }
        }
    }
    int flag=0,val=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;++j)
        {
            if(a[i][j]==1&&t[i][j]==INT_MAX)
            {   
                flag=-1;
                break;
            }   
            else if(a[i][j]==1)
            val=max(t[i][j],val);
        }
    }
    if(flag==-1)
    val=-1;
/*  else
    {

        for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<n;++j)
            cout<<t[i][j]<<" ";
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }*/
    cout<<val;
}
```

However, this recurs indefinitely.  Why?

Comment: Since `t` and `count` don't affect the flow of control, you might as well remove those too as you simplify the function to track down the error.

Comment: t and count are important...see I am sending count+1 in recursion and t stores the count value..

Comment: Is this a homework problem or project?  It's somewhat difficult to understand what you're asking here.  I'd recommend explaining the background and your current approach then including a shorter code example.

Comment: its actually some interview question which I was trying

Comment: Too long, too much recur, too many returns commented out, too many single-letter var names, complex multi-dim array indexing, no aparrent attempt at debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Please ask a question in the form, why is this program running in an infinite loop or something like this.

take a look at your recursion

```
 recur(a,t,count+1,i+1,j,n); // 1
 recur(a,t,count+1,i,j+1,n); // 2
 recur(a,t,count+1,i,j-1,n); // 3
 recur(a,t,count+1,i-1,j,n); // 4
```

the path (1)->(4)->(1)->(4) is infinite, because you increase i and then you decrease i.